# add to cart and continue shopping url in single button

Tags: magento-1.8, cart, url

I am using magento 1.8.
I am having custom add-to-cart button, that label is **"Add to cart and continue shopping"**

Magento have these both option seperatly, **"Add-to-cart"** and **"continue Shopping"**
How can I combine both the option in single button or click.
I mean when user clicks on **"Add to cart and continue shopping"** it need to add the product to cart and redirect to home page/product list page..

THANK YOU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved It,
First add the product to cart

```
Mage::getModel("checkout/cart")->addProduct($_product)->save();
```

Then call URL where you need to redirect [Below I am redirecting to home page]

```
$url = Mage::getUrl('home');
echo $url
```

Thanks You lot, Guys

Comment: If this answer worked, please verify it. So that others should also know what actually helped, before reading all comments

Answer (score 2):

system->configuration->sales section ->checkout->shopping cart->After Adding a Product Redirect to Shopping Cart=no

mage->checkout->controllers->cartcontroller->
you need to work on addAction method (you can directly give $url=home url or product list url.and you need to override cartcontroller).

```
if (!$this->_getSession()->getNoCartRedirect(true)) {
                if (!$cart->getQuote()->getHasError()) {
                    $message = $this->__('%s was added to your shopping cart.', Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($product->getName()));
                    $this->_getSession()->addSuccess($message);
                }
                $this->_goBack();
            }
```

........... ....

```
$url = $this->_getSession()->getRedirectUrl(true);
            if ($url) {
                $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
            } else {
                $this->_redirectReferer(Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCartUrl());
            }
```

Comment: I need to redirect after adding the product to cart

Comment: mage->checkout->controllers->cartcontroller->you need to work on addAction method ->if (!$this->_getSession()->getNoCartRedirect(true)) {
                if (!$cart->getQuote()->getHasError()) {
                    $message = $this->__('%s was added to your shopping cart.', Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($product->getName()));
                    $this->_getSession()->addSuccess($message);
                }
                $this->_goBack();
            }